# Elasticsearch query unique items by attribute

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document structure:

```
[
    {
        "email": "a@a.com",
        "event": "delivered",
    },
    {
        "email": "a@a.com",
        "event": "opened",
    },
    {
        "email": "a@a.com",
        "event": "clicked",
    },
    {
        "email": "b@b.com",
        "event": "delivered",
    },
    {
        "email": "c@c.com",
        "event": "delivered",
    },
    {
        "email": "c@c.com",
        "event": "opened",
    }
]
```

I would like to query those email addresses which were delivered, but not opened and not clicked.

Is there a one query solution for this or I can do this application side logic?

Answer (score 0):

Map the list to [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/nested.html) using the following query

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "documet_type": {
            "properties": {
                "list": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "email": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "event": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "list",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "list.event": {
                        "value": "delivered"
                    }
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

[Innerhits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) will return you the list of all events with event as delivered.

Comment: And if I have multiple events for the same email address? I need only those which have only the delivered event.

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you are trying to explain.

Comment: I the example I posted, I have multiple events for the same email address. I would like to query the following:
- those email addresses where event is delivered but not (opened or clicked)
- those email addresses where event is opened but not clicked
I hope this helps.